# Crash-Free Users Metrics in Firebase

Tags: firebase, crashlytics

Firebase Crashlytics dashboard shows "Crash-free statistics". How to get/enable Crash-Free Users Statistics/Metrics in Firebase ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Crash-Free User metrics helps monitor the health of your app releases and the effectiveness of recent improvements to your app. Monitoring your crash free users statistic over time allows you to see changes in stability easily. Firebase calculates this metric using [Google Analytics](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/) for Firebase data. In order to populate the chart in your Crashlytics dashboard must include the Google Analytics for Firebase SDK. Once populated, you can see the percentage of users who did not experience a crash in your app over the selected timeframe and filter by build. You can see the same data in the latest release section of the Google Analytics for Firebase dashboard. To get started, add Google Analytics for Firebase to your [iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/ios/start/) or [Android](https://firebase.google.com/docs/analytics/android/start/) app.

Comment: How does this differ from Fabric Crash-Free User metrics? I know that the metrics from Firebase Crashlytics uses Google Analytics and Fabric Crashlytics uses Answers. However, I just wanna know how do they differ.

Comment: @dev.for.fun, there are no major differences between the Fabric Vs Firebase "Crash Free User" metric. The only thing that sets them apart is that both Answer/GA for Firebase use their own algorithms to calculate these numbers and Fabric reports crash-free experience on "a given day" where GA does so over the "selected timeframe" ( 24 hr, 7 days, 30 days etc)

Comment: The big difference is that google want all your data in order to show you anything valuable.

Comment: But is this an absolute value? I would assume that there will be such few crashes that the "absolute number of crash free users" will depend mostly on the number of users and not on the number crashes...